mavenrc_pre.cmd file it's ignored when run configuration from eclipse
I have a file mavenrc_pre.cmd in %home% directory that set's the JAVA_HOME env var to a specific jdk version.
If I run, for example:
mvn clean install
from cmd line everything work's ok, but if I run the same maven goal from eclipse configuration the mavenrc_pre.cmd it's ignored.
The mavenrc_pre.cmd content:
set JAVA_HOME=C:\winapp\Java\17.0.9-jdk
The eclipse configuration is pointing to the same maven installation.
Can anyone please understand why this is happening?
Even if I change it directly in the mvn.cmd file (like in this post) JAVA_HOME is still ignored.

The Java to run Maven can be set in the Maven run configuration in the tab JRE.

Eclipse doesn't execute system Maven. It has a built-in Maven version that is integrated into Eclipse build system.

Hi Robert and howlger, thanks for the answer, yes I know I can set the jdk in this tab, but in this tab I purposely set the jdk 8 so that then maven during execution switches to java 17 because it uses whatever is in the mavenrc_pre.cmd file . For example, if I use the cmd line and set JAVA_HOME to jdk 8 and then run maven it changes to jdk 17, but this is not happening if it is run through the eclipse configuration. As for maven, I have another maven installed and in the eclipse configuration I set it to use this maven.

Basically I'm doing this because we have a java program that runs in java 8 and that uses eclipse configuration to launch another process that has to run in java 17.

You might duplicate the Maven run configuration to have one to run with Java 8 and one to run with Java 17. Alternative, you can run a Maven that is installed on your system as external tool.

That is a possibility that I have already tried but as this java program (in practice it is an eclipse) has a very old version (2014 and we cannot use a more recent one) and does not accept configurations that use java 17 as it is not compatible :(

What is preventing you from using the latest Eclipse version?

This is a very old and complex project that in the next few years will be deprecated (a new website is being created to replace it), this approach would be to make it possible to use it for a few more years.

The latest Eclipse version also supports very old Java version like 1.1, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, etc. So what exactly preventing you from using the latest Eclipse version?

This project was made using eclipse Kepler RPC, and uses very old library's which simply makes it almost impossible to update them all to support Java 17, some of them have already been discontinued and don't even have support. The upgrade is not worth the time investment as an alternative is being developed.

You can use the latest Eclipse IDE without the need to update something in your projects. The Java used to run Eclipse and the Java versions used in your projects are completely independent.

Yes, we are considering trying to update the eclipse version, but we have already tried it once and it was a real nightmare because we use old m2e libraries that cause a lot of problems in the most current versions of eclipse.
But if we don't find a solution we will try this approach again.
